# Form submit in html

Tags: html, forms

Page 215 of the CF9 Web Application Construction Kit volume 1 says
"Most newer browsers actually do not require a submit button at all, and force a submit if the Enter (Windows) or Return (Mac) key is pressed."

Q: Is that true?

Q: If that's true, then what is considered heretofore said "newer browsers".

Q: Should I discontinue having a submit buttons on my forms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes it's true in some instances.
2. I believe that FireFox and Chrome will both allow submissions without a submit button.
3. Absolutely not. Users expect to have a button to click to finish a form 99% of the time. Also, the form will only submit if a form field has focus, such as an input field. So if your form ends with a group of radio buttons or checkboxes, then Enter or Return may not submit the form.

I would recommend that you keep that submit button there unless you have a *really* good reason to remove it.